# Tensorflow issue with saving the model

Tags: tensorflow

I finally installed the GPU version and since then I have had this issue:

```
WARNING:absl: Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op 
while saving (showing 2 of 2). These functions will not be directly callable after 
loading.
```

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure if this warning can be an issue. However it is even shown in the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load?hl=en#the_keras_api). I think you can safely ignore it and you should still be okay, unless you really need to “use” the untraced function.

Comment: I tested my model with this message and the model didn't work at all

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Does it shows an error message? @MaxMelichov

Comment: No, it didn't have a good pred score